Homogeneous spaces for unipotent groups are isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^n$
I am looking for a proof of the following fact: Let $U$ be a unipotent algebraic group over $\mathbb{C}$. Then any $U$-homogeneous space is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^n$.

Context:
Let $G$ be a reductive algebraic group over $\mathbb{C}$ with Borel subgroup $B$.
Let $U$ be the unipotent radical of $B$.
Let $LG$ and $L^+G$ be the loop and arc groups of $G$.
The flag variety $G/B$ and the affine Grassmanian $\mathrm{Gr}_G:=LG/L^+G$ both have Schubert stratifications:
$$
\begin{align*}
G/B &= \bigsqcup_{w\in W} BwB/B \\
\mathrm{Gr}_G &= \bigsqcup_{\mu\in X_{\ast}(T)^+} L^+G \cdot t^\mu L^+G
\end{align*}
$$
The cell $BwB/B$ in $G/B$ is an affine space of dimension $\ell(w)$.
The cell $L^+G\cdot t^\mu L^+G$ in $\mathrm{Gr}_G$ admits a map to the partial flag variety $G/P_\mu$ whose fibers are affine spaces.
I think the affineness of these spaces can be explained by the fact that they are homogeneous spaces for unipotent groups: in the case of the flag variety, $BwB/B = UwB/B$, while in the case of the affine Grassmanian, the fibers of the map $L^+G \cdot t^\mu L^+G \rightarrow G/P_\mu$ are homogeneous spaces for the (pro-)unipotent radical of $L^+G$.
I can prove these facts for $G = GL_n$, but I am hoping to do so in a way which is independent of the choice of group $G$.

There are several proofs of this statement. A quite elegant one is by induction on the dimension of $U/U'$.
(1) If $\dim U/U' = 1$, then one finds a one-dimensional $G_a \subset U$ such that $G_a \cap U = \{e\}$. It follows that $U/U'$ is an orbit under the action of $G_a$ by left-multiplication, hence $U/U'$ isomorphic to $G_a$.
(2) In general, the normalizer of $U'$ in $U$ strictly contains $U'$, and so we can find a $G_a \subset U$ not contained in $U'$ which normalizes $U'$. Setting $U'' = U' G_a$ we see that the canonical map $U/U' \to U/U''$ is a principal $G_a$-bundle. By induction, $U/U''$ is an affine space $\mathbb{C}^n$. Since every principal $G_a$-bundle over an affine variety is trivial, we get $U/U' = U/U'' \times \mathbb{C} = \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$.
PS. A general proof in arbitrary characteristic can be found in the book "Groupes algébriques" by Demazure-Gabriel: IV, § 4, Corollaire 3.16.

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review

This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker. - From Review
